# Ways to make my left table display all its rows

Tags: mysql, sql

We want to show ALL Students from the left table (Student) and their average exams score.
Whether they they did any exams at all and that their name isn't in the (Score) Table.

The following SQL code almost works but it fails to bring us 1 student (1 row), the one that is not inside the (Score) table because that student didn't do any of the exams.

```sql
SELECT
    st.ID "Student ID",
    st.Name "Name",
    round(avg(scr.Score)) "Av Score"
FROM
    Student st LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Score scr on st.ID = scr.Player
WHERE
    scr.ID < 9 -- Because records greater have been known to be false and we don't need them
GROUP BY
    st.ID
```

We should see all the Student names.
Not really sure what am doing wrong but thank you for any advice.

Comment: because you have `scr.ID < 9` in the `WHERE` clause, effectively making your join an `INNER JOIN`. Move that condition to the `LEFT JOIN` condition :- `ON st.ID = scr.Player AND scr.ID < 9`

Answer (score 1):

This works but i would prefer not to hardcode in the where clause of the 2nd query in this union :

```
select st.ID "Student ID", st.Name "Name", round(avg(scr.Score),0) "Average Score"
from Student st LEFT OUTER JOIN Score scr on st.ID = scr.Student
where scr.ID < 9
Group by st.ID
union
select st.ID "Student ID", st.Name "Name", round(avg(scr.Score),0) "Average Score"
from Student st LEFT OUTER JOIN Score scr on st.ID = scr.Student
where st.ID = 'Z'
Group by st.ID
```

By the way, I did switched to SQLServer 2017 using free software on the web that allows us to switched from MySQL to SQLServer 2017 ) and this newly created UNION is still working but i first had to add the "decimal" argument value of 0 for the round function.

I mean, i would prefer using the following proposed code but somehow it's not working ?

```
SELECT
    st.ID "Student ID",
    st.Name "Name",
    round(avg(scr.Score)) "Av Score"
FROM
    Student st LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Score scr on st.ID = scr.Player
WHERE
    scr.ID < 9 -- Because records greater have been known to be false and we don't need them
GROUP BY
    st.ID
```

Comment: See mods to my answer

Answer (score 1):

An outer join works thus: If there are matching rows, they get joined (just like with an inner join). If there are no matching rows, you still get a joined row, but the columns of the outer joined table are set to null.

You want to outer join all scores below nine. Instead you outer join all scores:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN Score scr ON st.ID = scr.Player
```

Then you want to get rid of the higher scores with

```
WHERE scr.ID < 9
```

But in outer joined rows the scr.ID is null, and this clause dismisses these rows, too. Thus you end up with a mere inner join.

Instead outer join the scores below nine as intended:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN Score scr ON st.ID = scr.Player AND scr.ID < 9
```

Comment: Ok thanks to all but now am a little confused what should my final query look like ?

Comment: Then it seems you haven't understood my answer at all. I am showing you the two incorrect lines and the correct one. And I am explaining why the two original lines are incorrect and why they must be replaced by the correct one. What is there that you don't understand?

Comment: Agree. Logically the original query makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to use `ISNULL`

```sql
SELECT
    st.ID "Student ID",
    st.Name "Name",
    round(avg(ISNULL(scr.Score, -1)), 0) "Av Score"
FROM
    Student st LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Score scr on st.ID = scr.Player
WHERE
    scr.ID < 9 -- Because records greater have been known to be false and we don't need them
GROUP BY
    st.ID,
    st.Name
```

In this case, you will see that anyone with `-1` score is a person who did not take the exams. It could be useful since score of `0` could come from a very bad exam taker

Also, while this is posibble, try to avoid spaces and system words in the identifiers and aliases

Here is running code https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5ab664ba7a29344a094e5aca9cd35e9e

Comment: hi to all and thanks for quick repies. When i try adding the isnull it generates the followig error message : "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'". I am able to have the expected result by doing a UNION and in the second query (the new one i added) is identical besides the where clause is now where st.ID = 'Z' because i know that is the only row missing that comes from this left side table with very few records (let's 15). any other suggestions ?

Comment: @sanchoniathon which DB are you using, SQL SERVER?

Comment: DOCS: *Using ISNULL with AVG* --> `SELECT AVG(ISNULL(Weight, 50))`

Comment: yes SQL server.

Comment: `where st.ID = 'Z'` -- this sounds like a hack job

Comment: not sure to understand the "this sounds like a hack job" ? I just tried with the SELECT AVG(ISNULL(Weight, 50)) but now i get the following error message : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT AVG(ISNULL(Weight, 50)) "Average Score" from Player pl LEFT OUTER JOIN Sc' at line 1         so i guess i'm using MySQL ?...

Comment: yea, but `Weight` is just an example. you need to use your real column

Comment: @sanchoniathon I ran syntax checked on the code posted in **my** answer. Valid

Comment: ok i also did that but still error message.

Comment: @sanchoniathon As they say... "Works on my machine" :-)

Comment: @sanchoniathon Looks like there was an issue with `ROUND`. I modified the answer and added a fiddle for you to see